# Table row has border yet have spacing inbetween

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

Image link: [www.ray-tsai.com/code_table.jpg](http://www.ray-tsai.com/code_table.jpg)

jsfiddle for experimenting:
[jsfiddle.net/s93f4/1](http://jsfiddle.net/s93f4/1)

I understand that having border around tr must apply

```
border-collapse: collapse;
```

then would be possible to have spacing in between too like image shows ..
anyone has done this before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a border with border : 1 px solid;

Than use margin to add spacing don't know why you want border collapse it removes spacing

Comment: but the border of the tr won't be connected if it's set border-collapse:seperate : ( it looks like a row of blocks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s93f4/1/

see the table separate's tr border:solid 1px red; doesn't work 
unless parent table is borer-collapse:collapse 
___
apply border on table-separate's td only make a row of separate blocks

Comment: how about add a TR in between the others as a seperator like this to create the space, and specific whatever height you want:      '<tr style="height:3px; border:none;" class="separator">
    </tr>'